# Ubuntu always takes boot priority over windows

Tags: windows, ubuntu, multi-boot, uefi

So currently I have my computer set up to dual boot Windows and Ubuntu. The issue that is occurring is that whenever the Ubuntu drive is plugged in my computer will always boot to Ubuntu, even when I select to boot from the Windows drive in the boot menu. when the Ubuntu drive is unplugged the windows drive boots to windows just fine. Windows doesn't show up in grubs either.

My computer is configured in UEFI mode and if it has the option to run in legacy mode I cant find it. Secure boot is off. Motherboard is Gigabyte 990FXA-UD3. Windows is installed on a SSD and Ubuntu is installed on a HDD.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have USB taking priority over your motherboard's internal SATA port in the boot process. Go into your board's UEFI configuration and see if you can change the boot order so that it looks for the internal drive before anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to check your systems boot order for your system.  I looked up and found [your manual here](https://download.gigabyte.com/FileList/Manual/mb_manual_ga-990fxa-ud3_e.pdf) and Chapter 2 discusses the boot options.  You'll want to press  at boot when the splash screen displays to get into the settings, then Advanced BIOS Features.  From there you'll see several options near the bottom for First, Second, and Third boot options.

Since you did say that you can even select the Windows drive to boot from that the system is still booting to Ubuntu, you may have a bootloader issue.  If Ubuntu installed grub to the main boot drive upon install to go alongside Windows, it may be loading and trying to find Linux no matter what you do.

If this is the case you can either [reinstall the Windows bootloader](https://forums.tomshardware.com/faq/how-to-repair-efi-bootloader-in-windows-10.3275168/) or you can also [change the default grub boot order](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/12/how-to-change-grub-boot-order-or.html) from inside Ubuntu.